# Append script in head by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want append `script` in head if there is tag `<script>` in the body, i try as following but it don't work, How can done it?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rYXJx/

JS:

```
var TAREA = $('body').find('textarea').length;

if(TAREA > 0){ 
    $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="files/js/nicEdit.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });</script>');
    };
```

Comment: I don't see how your demo could work. What is nicEditors?

Comment: A literal `</script>` inside a `<script>` tag will break the script tag!

Comment: adding elements to the `<head>` portion of the DOM will have no effect after the page is rendered. Therefore, even though you are appending the `script` tag, nothing will happen. You'll want to use a more dynamic approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add DOM element script to head section?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784920/how-to-add-dom-element-script-to-head-section)

Answer (score 4):

You can use jquery getScript function:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

so the correct code looks like the below:

```
 $.getScript('files/js/niceEdit.js');
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems in your script is that the `</script>` inside the string literal actually breaks the outer `<script>` tag. You might notice these characters in your page which seem to come out of nowhere:

> ');};

Secondly, while it is still possible to inject a `<script>` tag in the head, there is no direct/easy/cross-browsr way of knowing when the script has finished loading. And you cannot use a script before it is loaded completely.

Best solution is to use [`jQuery.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) which provides a callback. Use the callback to call `nicEditors.allTextAreas()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($("textarea").length > 0) {
        $.getScript("files/js/nicEdit.js", function () {
            // no need for onDomLoaded -- DOM is loaded at this point!
            nicEditors.allTextAreas();
        });
    }
});
```