# Using document.head.appendChild() to append a script tag that has an SRC attribute?

Tags: javascript

Any reason why the following code isn't working?

```
alert("1");
document.head.appendChild("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js\"></script>");
alert("2");
```

(I know it is breaking because the 1 is alerted but not the 2.)

What is the proper way to accomplish the same thing? Namely, to append a script tag to the document head, where the tag gets a .js file using the SRC attribute. I don't want it to write javascript inline.

Thanks!

Comment: what errors do you see in dev console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add DOM element script to head section?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784920/how-to-add-dom-element-script-to-head-section)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`element.appendChild` expects a node not a string. You should first create the node and set the attributes and then append it.

[element.appendChild Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild)

```
var sc = document.createElement("script");
sc.setAttribute("src", "https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js");
sc.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
document.head.appendChild(sc);
```

For older browsers (IE < 9 etc.) that doesn't support [document.head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head)

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(sc);
```

Answer (score 8):

This will do what the original poster wants without creating a new object.

```
document.head.innerHTML += "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js\"></script>";
```

The script will be appended to the end of the existing head section which may not be what you want.

Believe it or not this will put your script at the start of the head section without erasing the existing head section:

```
document.head.innerHTML = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js\"></script>" + document.head.innerHTML;
```