# Dynamic javascript <script> tag injection

Tags: javascript, html, aem

I am working in client project, where some code within script tag is dynamically injected into the head tag of the DOM. Those lines of code are not present in the project repo. I am working in
AEM + React combination project. Kindly requesting to provide answer how those code are injected into the DOM. Thank you.

Comment: js is injected using the `document.head.append()` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22211642/6651840)

Comment: And what’s wrong with the methods shown here [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) like at **Dynamic Script Loading**?

Comment: There are so many question regarding that topic here on SO. So you need to explain why those don’t work for you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There can be high chances that they are getting added via Launch or DTM. We can insert custom JS at runtime into sites using these applications. I would request you to check with your clients on the same. Someone in the tech team would be having much more details on the tools used.