# How to make use of external JavaScript source file in JSP through simple java class

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am creating one project in which I am making call to a JavaScript function which resides in *index.jsp* from my java class ( .java file). As in this context we shouldnt write `<script>` tag in our index.jsp, what should I do if I want to make use of some dependent .js file like ***stomp.js***  source file in my index.jsp file??

Comment: How do you mean with "we shouldnt write `<script>` tag in our index.jsp"?

Comment: means if we want to call a JavaScript function from our java class, we make of `ScriptEngineManager` and run that function. In these case we define only function body in the JavaScript file.

Comment: You could write a Javascript function which adds the `<script>` tag to the DOM.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784920/how-to-add-dom-element-script-to-head-section