# Including Javascript file inside another Javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have two classes, say `ParentClass` and `ChildClass` in 2 separate files. I am directly invoking a function inside `ChildClass` and I want to include the `ParentClass` dynamically when the `ChildClass` is invoked. I **DON'T** want to use any **external library or packages** such as `jQuery`, `require.js` etc. Also I **DON'T** want to use `ES6` or `nodejs require` as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file), because of browser compatibility issues.

---

Here is how my files looks like,

**parentclass.js**

```
var ParentClass = function(param1, param2) {
    // Class related code here
};

ParentClass.prototype.parentClassFunction = function() {
     // Code for the function here...
};
```

**childclass.js**

```
var ChildClass = function(param1, param2) {
    // Some class related code here...

    this.parentClassFunction();

    // Some other code...
};

ChildClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);
```

**HTML file**

```
.....
<head>
  ...
  <script src="childclass.js"></script>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    var value = new ChildClass(10, 20);
  </script>
  ...
</body>
```

---

Is there any way by which I can achieve this? Your help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance. :)

**NOTE**: I had a brief look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235321/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-dynamically), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294/dynamically-load-a-javascript-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file) question.

Comment: maybe write a script in <head/> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784920/how-to-add-dom-element-script-to-head-section

Comment: Or using a bundler like webpack

Comment: @BalajMarius I have imported script inside <head> tag. I will edit the question in more clearer way.

Comment: @bharadhwaj what do you mean by "..and I want to include the ParentClass dynamically when the ChildClass is invoked"

Comment: @BalajMarius I mean, when `ChildClass` is invoked, it uses functions in `ParentClass`, but I don't what to add every dependent js file manually in HTML and rather want to choose it dynamically when needed. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to bundle all the files with a precompiler or something like that.

in your childclass.js you should use require('parentclass.js') or import use something like Browserify to solve the dependencies automagically.

Here are some links:
- http://browserify.org/
- https://webpack.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

If you are use ES6 features you can use import:

for example:

`import { Childclass } from '/path/to/childclass';`

Here is the documentation for import:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: I have mentioned in the question, I **don't** want ES6 because of Browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Oh sorry for that

Comment: Why you don't try to use commonjs to have require like nodejs have:http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Comment: I am trying to make a library with minimal requirements, so I don't want to add the overhead of packages. That is the reason why.