# Adding dyanmic javascript as a string in string. How to use \ character? Facing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token."

Tags: javascript, c#, webview

```
Public WebView view;  
var url = "javascript:(function() { var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);var script = document.createElement('script'); script.type = 'text/javascript'; script.innerHTML =\""+  content + "\";parent.appendChild(script)})()"; 
view.LoadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add DOM element script to head section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784920/how-to-add-dom-element-script-to-head-section)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(content) to encode this string:

```
\
"
'
```

into this:

```
\\
\"
\'
```