# Insert inline script to the index.html with env variable

Tags: reactjs, webpack, environment-variables, inline-scripting

I have index.html where I want to load hotjar tracking code (only inline script), but it depends on the env variable.
I tried to use webpack DefinePlugin

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
    }),
```

and get this env, but I can get it only from react component.

```
componentWillMount() {
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
    document.getElementById('hotjar').innerHTML = env === 'production' ? "...script1" : "...script2" 
  }
```

Then I used 'innerHTML' to put my script to the index.html, but it doesn't work as I expected.

Here is the body of index.html

```
<body>
 <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
  <script id="hotjar">
  </script>
</body>
```

So, I need to get it within some script on index.html or something like this?
Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: "env variable", "get this env, but I can get it only from react component" , what is that and can you please clarify?  What platform?  Please provide something that you have tried so we can help fix it rather than simply "I tried several things" and "I am uncertain what to do".   "hotjar tracking code" - what code, we see no code.

Comment: maybe now it's better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add DOM element script to head section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784920/how-to-add-dom-element-script-to-head-section)

Comment: Also lots of information here https://stackoverflow.com/q/610995/125981

Comment: Thanks a lot! The last one helped me

Answer (score 0):

You can use different files for each environment. Like `tracking_test.js` `tracking_prod.js` and use webpack to pick the appropriate file while building and rename it to `tracking.js`. Refer the `tracking.js` in the html file. By this means, you don't ship the unnecessary code.

If you want to continue with your modifying innerHTML route, look into https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet They have nicer APIs for the same.

Comment: The problem is that I need to use only inline script