# How can I add an external javascript tag to an Ember JS app without touching the index.html?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, single-page-application, ember-cli

Is it possible to load an external javascript resource in Ember without touching index.html?

If I *could* add to html, I would simply add the following and it works.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var my_data = [{ foo: "bar", value: 1.234 }];</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://external.com/file.js"></script>
</body>
```

I tried appending the tag using jQuery, but it won't actually launch the javascript on the client:

```
$('body').append('<script type="text/javascript">var my_data = [{ foo: "bar", value: 1.234 }];</script>');
$('body').append('<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://external.com/file.js"></script>');
```

Where `file.js` sends `my_data` to `external.com`.

Unfortunately I'm building a single-page-app for a client without access to `index.html`. What do you recommend to append the two script tags? Is it possible?

---

It gets worse. I need to send `my_data` to `external.com` *again* after a user click event.

In a traditional html environment I would do the following: (this works)

page1.html:

```
    <a href="/page2.html">user action to track</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">var my_data = [{ foo: "bar", value: 1234 }];</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://external.com/file.js"></script>
</body>
```

page2.html:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">var my_data = [{ foo: "qux", value: 4321 }];</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://external.com/file.js"></script>
</body>
```

How can I accomplish the same result in Javascript, on a single-page-app, without touching index.html?

Comment: How is that even possible that you do not have access to index.html? Some outdated ember version with some weird self-made build process?

Comment: Does your app uses [Content Security Policy](https://content-security-policy.com/) (CSP)?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using ember-cli, you can try [ember-cli-head](https://github.com/ronco/ember-cli-head) addon.

Otherwise, you can try to combine one of js techniques described [in answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784920/how-to-add-dom-element-script-to-head-section) and [application initializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/initializers/)

Comment: The StackOverflow question mentioned above also tells you why your jQuery approach is failing. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18785133/3167221) answer. Rewriting your jQuery approach in vanilla JS should solve your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can install addon `ember-cli-inline-content`

Then add into your index.html inside `<body>`

```
{{content-for "your-script-name"}}
```

Then inside `ember-cli-build.js`

```
    ...
    inlineContent: {
      'your-script-name' : {
        file: './public/assets/externalJs/your-script.js'
        }
      }
```

Your external script `public/assets/externalJs/your-script.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var my_data = [{ foo: "bar", value: 1234 }];
</script>
```

Run `ember s` again

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you load `your-script.js` from a remote server? As in, `https://external.com/your-script.js`?

Answer (score 3):

The vendor directory, which is a common home for third-party JavaScript that is copied and pasted in.

In your case download the external/third-party JavaScript file and paste it under `app-name/vendor/ext-js-file-name.js`

Then you need to import `ext-js-file-name.js` in `ember-cli-build.js` file

```
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  ...
  app.import('vendor/ext-js-file-name.js');
  ...
}
```

When this is done kindly `restart` your ember server. So the js files which is imported under `ember-cli-build.js` get compiled included at the head of your ember application, which can then be used globally at various places in your application.

There is no further need of including the js under `index.html`

Please look at the asset compilation from the official [ember documentaton](https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/assets-and-dependencies/) page if you need further details about assets, dependencies and compilations.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to call the js remotely? What if the remote file is updated?

Comment: First thing is that no JS file will be dynamically updated each and every sec or day. There will a release cycle. So you no need to worry about that. Please follow my above solution or even you can give a try for below options too,
1) Look is there any `npm package` for the js you are looking for. If so include that package in your `package.json` file. 
2) You can add this `document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript' src='ext-js-file-name.js'></script>");` or 
`$.getScript('https/path/to/ext-js-file-name.js')` in your js file

Answer (score 0):

Run this somewhere:

```
<script>
 var my_data = [{ foo: "bar", value: 1.234 }];
 var jq = document.createElement('script');
 jq.src = "https://external.com/file.js?version=20190320114623";
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
</script>
```

Control de caching of the .js file by adding something you know that will change each time the file changes (timestamp of file modification date, or variable you can control).

*Edit*